# Positivity constraints in optimization

Tags: optimization

How do you enforce positivity constraints in non-linear optimization (e.g. a constraint $x > 0$)? I remember there being a good reason for why most models use non-negativity constraints.

Comment: How about the KKT conditions? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions

Comment: @matt:They handle non-negative and equality constraints.

Comment: :You could use "Log Barrier methods". I will post an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the following:
 $$\begin{array}{rll}
 \min_x& f(x)&\\
 \text{subject to}& g_i(x)\leq0 &\text{for each }i\\
 & h_i(x)=0 &\text{for each }j \\
 \end{array}$$

For $\alpha>0$ we define the [log barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_function) [penalty function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method), $P_\alpha$, to be:

$$ P_\alpha(x)=f(x)-\frac1\alpha\sum_i\log(-g_i(x))+\alpha\sum_jh_j(x)^2 $$

where $x$ must be **strictly feasible**, i.e. $g_i(x)<0$ for each $i$, in order for the log term to be defined.

We seek to minimise $P_\alpha(x)$. The idea is that the boundary of the feasible region (i.e $g_i(x)=0$) acts a a *barrier* for $x$ close to $0$.

Comment: Should that be $\log(-g_i(x))$? I think you have an extra left parenthesis.